# Randomly generate 2 dates per week over 2 years

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

How do I write an excel formula, which randomly picks 2 dates in each week over a 2 year period, where:

1. The 2 dates per week are not the same as each other

So this should not happen:

```
05/02/2015
05/02/2015
```

2. The first date in any given week is always before the second date of that same week:

So this should not happen:

```
06/02/2015
05/02/2015
```

3. Where Sunday is the beginning of the week and Saturday is the end of the week:

Here is an example of what I am after:

```
week    day     date
1       1       01/01/2015
1       2       03/01/2015
2       1       05/01/2015
2       2       08/01/2015
```

And so on, all the way to the end of `2016`.

This is what I have so far, but this only randomly gives me a day of a week, and doesn't fulfill any of the criteria I've described above:

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(ROUND((RAND()*(7-1)+1),0)),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
```

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this "evenly distributed randomness" with just a spreadsheet formula. My first (naive) approach would be to partition the desired period (2 years) into weeks (array of arrays) and then iterate and randomize each week.

Comment: I posted a solution below.....but just to comment on the CHOOSE formula. Using `ROUND` with `RAND` here gives you a "skewed" distribution - Saturday and Sunday are less likely to appear than other days - better to use INT to get a random number between 1 and 7 like `=INT(RAND()*7+1)`....or use `=RANDBETWEEN(1,7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `21` different combinations of 2 days in a week - to ensure an even distribution you can use a helper column, so assuming your weeks start at `A2` and days at `B2` (always showing 1 then 2 in days column for each week) then use this formula in `D2`

`=IF(B2=1,RANDBETWEEN(1,21),"")`

and this formula in `C2`

`=IF(B2=1,E$1+MATCH(D2,{1,7,12,16,19,21})-8+A2*7,C1+D1-LOOKUP(D1,{1,7,12,16,19,21})+1)`

where `E1` contains the start date (a Sunday) of week 1

fill both formulas down the column

You can hide column D if required

See example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gunjuuhavso4y0k/rand%20days.xlsx?dl=0)